# Pytorch: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torch

I am trying to load a model `state_dict` I trained on Google Colab GPU, here is my code to load the model:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

model = models.resnet50()
num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, n_classes)
model.load_state_dict(copy.deepcopy(torch.load("./models/model.pth",device)))
model = model.to(device)
model.eval()
```

Here is the error:

> state_dict = state_dict.copy()
>
> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'copy'

Pytorch :

```
>>> import torch
>>> print (torch.__version__)
1.4.0
>>> import torchvision
>>> print (torchvision.__version__)
0.5.0
```

Please help I have searched everywhere to no avail

[full error details][1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/s22DL.png

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I am guessing this is what you did by mistake.
You saved the function

`torch.save(model.state_dict, 'model_state.pth')`

instead of the state_dict()

`torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model_state.pth')`

Otherwise, everything should work as expected. (I tested the following code on Colab)

Replace `model.state_dict()` with `model.state_dict` to reproduce error

```py
import copy
model = TheModelClass()
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model_state.pth')
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.load_state_dict(copy.deepcopy(torch.load("model_state.pth",device)))
```

Comment: I solved my issue using your answer. Thank you, @cozek

Answer (score 2):

because you saved your model

`torch.save(model.state_dict, 'model_state.pth')`
instead of

`torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model_state.pth')`

as result you saved function pointer of your model.
for this problem you must load your data like this:

`model.load_state_dict(copy.deepcopy(torch.load("./models/model.pth",device)()))`

instead of

`model.load_state_dict(copy.deepcopy(torch.load("./models/model.pth",device)))`

from
`torch.load("./models/model.pth",device)` you can see your model layer details and gain other good data.